# dBSet.Local.Clear is throwing an InvalidOperationException in a WPF application using EF 6

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding

I'm using EF 6 in a WPF application. I'm trying to build a layered architecture that abstracts the database specific code
from the rest of the application. I'm taking the approach of databinding instances of DbSet<>.Local to my UI controls in order to ease the burden 
of change tracking. I'm keeping the context around for a long time, i.e. from the time a new database is opened until the time that
it is closed. According to my research it seemed that this is a recommended approach for versions of EF after 4.1 based on this article from Microsoft
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj574514) even though it doesn't seem to be a popular choice.

However, I'm receiving exceptions when I try to do the simplest of things. Currently, I've got it narrowed down to this one exception that occurs when I attempt to clear
all entities from DbSet.Local. See the line of code in MVPModel.Clear() in the code below. Basically, it's attempting to execute a: DbSet.Local.Clear().

Am I destined to have trouble with this approach?

I use this class to bind to the UI in a MVP-style architecture.

```
public class MVPModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ConcreteModel> Models { get; set; }

    public void Attach(Database db)
    {
        this.Models = db.GetRepository<ConcreteModel>();
    }

    public void Detach()
    {
        this.Models = null;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        // Throwns an InvalidOperationException with the message
        // The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified. 
        Models.Clear(); 
    }
}


public class ModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Int32 _id;

    [Key]
    public Int32 Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this._id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_id != value)
            {
                _id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }
    }

}

public class ConcreteModel : ModelBase
{
    // ...
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ConcreteModel> Models { get; set; }

}
```

I create a wrapper around my EF database context that releases the unmanaged resources associated with DbContext.

```
public class Database : IDisposable
{
        private MyDbContext _dbContext;

        /// <summary>
        /// Get a reference to a collection
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">ObservableCollection generic template type</typeparam>
        /// <returns>An observable collection bound to the database repository</returns>
        public ObservableCollection<T> GetRepository<T>() 
        {
            ObservableCollection<T> retValue = null;

            var dbSet = this._dbContext.Set(typeof(T));

            if (dbSet != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Force a query against the database to load the data. Otherwise, .Local will always be
                    // empty. This is similar to called DbSet<T>.ToList() but it saves the overhead of creating 
                    // a throw away instance of List<>.
                    dbSet.Load();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Load will fail if the database hasn't been created yet, e.g. File|New
                    ex.Post();
                }

                retValue = dbSet.Local as ObservableCollection<T>;
                Debug.Assert(retValue != null);            
            }

            return retValue;
        }

    // ...
}
```

Here's a copy of the exception:

System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified. 
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.DetectChangesInProperty(Int32 ordinal, Boolean detectOnlyComplexProperties, Boolean detectOnly)
  InnerException:

Here's more from my call stack:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.DetectChangesInProperty(int ordinal = 0, bool detectOnlyComplexProperties = false, bool detectOnly = false) 
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.DetectChangesInProperties(bool detectOnlyComplexProperties = false) 
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChangesInScalarAndComplexProperties(System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry> entries = Count = 20)    
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChanges()  
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.DetectChanges()   
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.DetectChanges(bool force = false)   
...
```

Comment: What's the purpose of clearing the `Local` collection?